# Help me re-find this role-playing story

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, roleplaying, product-identification

I want to find this story again to inspire my fellow newer players to break the mold of role-playing.

I remember reading an incredibly inspiring [D&D probably] story about a player who was role-playing a Paladin "in disguise" as an awful lazy crotchety fighter so well, that the players thought he was being a useless and rude when he was actually being incredibly helpful.

As I remember it, when other players fell he would kick them and yell "Get up you lazy asses!" when he was healing them with Lay Upon Hands, and giving them bonuses to their checks with yells like "Coward!" and "Idiot!" The DM was shrugging and pretending to just give them bonuses and extra health to play along. The players were so fed up with his name-calling while seeming to outright refuse to assist the party in any way, that they were going to ask him to leave when they were finally told his scheme.

Does anyone else remember this story? Can you send me the link?
I feel like it was in the form of a forum post somewhere.

Comment: Consider also asking on   http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?30-Roleplaying-Games.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Good idea. Will do.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Rather than point people to a specific forum, we have [a meta question guiding people to select the forum alternative that best suits their needs](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) that we prefer to use. It avoids site favouritism from causing issues here.

Comment: @SSD: my mistake, will use that link in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case you're still looking for it, I found it on Google. It originated on 4chan, but has ended up on both reddit and imgur. You can find it below.

[image: The story]

Comment: What an amazing story.

Comment: Thank you! I am quite grateful. I will also use the other sites next time.

Comment: That's just awesome, I have to admit.